# Block-level raw partition backup for Linux?

Tags: linux, xen, netbackup, block-level

I have RAW LVM volumes I've exported as a snapshot from a Falconstor/EMC Symmetrix virtual SAN appliance.  Upon these logical volumes are Xen virtual guest servers which are present to a backup server (Linux box with netbackup client) when we mask the SAN snapshot (timemark) LUNs to the media server.

I'd like to send these guest images (which are within a LVM logical volume) from a SAN snapshot off to Netbackup for tape archival, without converting the guest image to a file on a filesystem readable by a netbackup client .

Whats the best way I can send the raw data from a physical volume (SAN lun) to Netbackup ?    I know its possible as the Oracle RMAN tool does this for Oracle ASM disks.. I'd like to do this with a linux native tool.

Thanks MUCH!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The agent to accomplish this is called "NetBackup Snapshot Client." It will handle snapping (or cloning) the LUN, presenting it to the media server, and performing the backup. EMC Clarrion and Symmetrix arrays are supported. I don't know if that includes a "Falconstor/EMC Symmetrix virtual SAN appliance."

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much.  The "Flashcopy/Flashbackup" within the Netbackup Snapshot Client will be our solution  of choice.

Answer (score 0):

DRBD should be able to do this for you.
http://www.drbd.org/

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just point whatever backup tool you have at the right /dev/ entries?